# Как перебросить пользователя на URL с которого он пришёл?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

Имеется закрытое авторизацией приложение на Angular

State авторизации имеет следующий вид:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('auth', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    resolve: {
      auth: function ($q, $auth, $rootScope, $state) {

        var dfd = $q.defer();

        $auth.isAuthorized()
          .then(
          function () {
            dfd.resolve();
          },
          function () {
            dfd.reject();
            $state.go('login');
          }
        );

        return dfd.promise;
      }
    }
  });
```

Работает это так: при переходе на любой state через провайдер $auth с методом isAuthorized() авторизован ли пользователь (смотрятся куки, если в них есть токен, то он отправляется на сервер, если возвращается положительный ответ, то по цепочке вверх он доходи до стейта auth и пользователь попадает туда, куда хотел )

Проблема возникает, когда пользователь не авторизовался (просрочен токен, или пользователь зашел впервые).

Когда провайдер аутентификации говорит что пользователь не авторизован, он переходит на state login. В контроллере login после успешной авторизации я могу отправить пользователя по любому URL, но как мне сохранить, по какому url пользователь перешёл вначале?

Использовать событие $locationChangeSuccess, у меня не получилось, поскольку сохранятся еще значения перехода на стейт login и стейт с url '/', а отфильтровать их я не смогу (Дело в том, что я не могу заранее определить по какому URL расположено приложение)

Comment: сделай рабочий пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) как это сейчас работает

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OlovmuGMzIvEO5qy4jEi?p=preview

Первый раз что-то писал в планкере, надеюсь будет понятно. Пользователь заходит на сайт по URL /?title='data', потом попадает на авторизацию, потом успешно логинится, и попадает на стейт с URL '/', вот тут мне хочется получить значение параметра title

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, это при переадресации добавлять текущий URL в качестве параметра. После успешной авторизации перекидывать обратно (взяв путь из этого параметра естественно).

Answer (score -1):

Там написано, как перенаправить на другую страницу в javascript
https://habrahabr.ru/post/250143/

Если кратко, то

`var a = window.location;` - узнать текущий адрес

`window.location = 'http://new-website.com/';` - установить адрес (т.е. перенаправить)